# How to map array outside of render function to setState?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, setstate, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to map over an array of a fetched API to separate the individual items with the same name, and setState based on that individual item property.  For instance, the array returns multiple different items with different latitudes and longitudes.  I am able to setState using a function in the onClick inside the render function, however I know this is bad practice.  I've tried moving the function outside of render and using onClick={this.functionName}, but this gives weird behavior.  What am I doing wrong?

here is the function I created outside of the render:

```
 mapItem = () => {
    const parks = [...this.state.parks];
    parks.map(item =>
      this.setState({
        lat: item.latitude,
        lng: item.longitude,
        zoom: 16
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (<h2 onClick={this.mapItem}>{item.name}</h2>)
    }
```

this works:

```
render() {
const { parks } = this.state;
    return(
{parks.map(item => (
<h2 onClick={() => this.setState({lat: item.latitude, 
             lng: item.longitude, zoom: 16})
             }>{item.name}</h2>
))
)}}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can move the onClick event handler outside of `render()`:

```
  handleClick = item => {
    this.setState({
      lat: item.latitude,
      lng: item.longitude,
      zoom: 16
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { parks } = this.state

    return (
      <>
        {parks.map(item => (
          <h2
            onClick={() => {
              this.handleClick(item)
            }}
          >
            {item.name}
          </h2>
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }
```

---

If you are trying to avoid any inline-functions in `render()` (because each render will create a new instance of that function), then you will have to create a separate component for each `parks`'s item:

```
// ParkItem functional component
const ParkItem = ({item}) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    this.props.setCoordinate({
      lat: item.latitude,
      lng: item.longitude,
      zoom: 16
    })
  }

  return <h2 onClick={handleClick}>{item.name}</h2>
}

class YourCurrentClass extends Component {
  setCoordinate = stateObj => {
    this.setState(stateObj)
  }

  render() {
    const { parks } = this.state

    return (
      <>
        {parks.map(item => (
          <ParkItem item={item} />
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default YourCurrentClass
```

Comment: Your comment on my answer is correct. Thank you for pointing this out. I must have read the post too quickly. I'm withdrawing my answer. 